# Distance based on Location Datatype

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables as below.

```
Cust_Master:
Cust_ID     Location                                        Distance  WHID
Cust10001   0xE6100000010CA986FD9E58172A40425A63D009685340  ???       ???
Cust10002   0xE6100000010C7BD976DA1A992F4071766B990C835340  ???       ???

WH_Master:
WH_ID   Location
WH1001  0xE6100000010C84F068E388C54240373811FDDA5B5340
WH1002  0xE6100000010C5BB1BFEC9E142A407DEA58A5F4675340
```

I would like to populate Distance and WHID in Cust_Master table based on location from WH_Master. Can some one throw some light on this.

Comment: There's a code-button `{ }` at the top of the editor that helps to format your code. The  countless `;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table with a cross join of distances and warehouse ID for the customers, then based on your requirement ( closest or furthest ) perform a select on this table and use the data to populate the customer table. You will need to define a function to compute distances, and then simply run an update based on  customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using STDistance() to compute distance and then a ranking function should work:

```
UPDATE Cust_Master 
SET 
    Distance = OuterQuery.Distance, 
    WHID = OuterQuery.WH_ID 
FROM (
    SELECT
        Cust_ID,
        WH_ID,
        Distance,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY WH_ID ORDER BY Distance ASC) AS 'RNK'
    FROM (
        SELECT Cust_ID, WH_ID, Cust_Master.Location.STDistance(WH_Master.Location) AS Distance
        FROM Cust_Master, WH_Master
    ) InnerQuery
    GROUP BY Cust_ID, WH_ID, Distance
) OuterQuery 
WHERE RNK = 1 AND Cust_Master.Cust_ID = OuterQuery.Cust_ID
```

This updates the `Cust_Master`table with the `WH_ID`and `Distance`to the closest `WH_ID`in `WH_Master`. If you want the `n` closest you can change `RNK = 1`to `RNK = n`